# How can I run a countdown and after it reaches 0 to press the button automatically?

Tags: javascript

I have two pieces of code that I managed to do as follows:
Countdown code:

```
<script>
setInterval(function up_time()  {
   var now = new Date();
   var mins = now.getMinutes();

   if (mins >= 0 && mins<60) {
       var target = new Date(now.getTime() + (59-mins)*60 + (60-secs));
   }

   var secondsRemaining = target.getTime() - now.getTime();
   var min = (Math.floor(secondsRemaining));

   document.getElementById("timer_rank1").innerHTML= min*999
},1000);
</script>
```

The code did actually counts one hour back and runs that hour over and over and keeps the ratio with refreshing the screen so it keeps that time exactly as it is
The following code:
Automatically clicks a button

```
<script>
var btn = document.querySelector("[data-pafe-form-builder-submit-form-id='lola']");
//console.log(btn);
setInterval(function(){
btn.click();
},3000); //this time 3 sce

//Handling of click event
btn.onclick=function(){ 
console.log('clicked');
}
</script>
```

Now I want to connect these seconds to a button, that as soon as it reaches 0 or gets close to 0 it clicks on the release I just can't think how to do it nicely

Answer (score 0):

you meant something like this?

```js
const btn = document.querySelector("#myBtn");

btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  console.log("btn clicked!!");
})

setInterval(function up_time() {
  var now = new Date();
  var mins = now.getMinutes();
  let secs = now.getSeconds();

  if (mins >= 0 && mins < 60) {
    var target = new Date(now.getTime() + (59 - mins) * 60 + (60 - secs));
  }

  // new lines
  if (59 - secs === 0) {
    btn.click();
  }
  // end new lines

  var secondsRemaining = target.getTime() - now.getTime();
  var min = (Math.floor(secondsRemaining));

  document.getElementById("timer_rank1").innerHTML = min * 999;
  document.getElementById("second").innerHTML = `Second: ${59 - secs}`;
}, 1000);
```

```html
<h1 id="timer_rank1"></h1>
<h1 id="second">Second: </h1>
<button id="myBtn">i will be clicked when second reaches 0</button>
```

Comment: Hi, thank you very much, but I need the code I wrote to be present because the timer should appear on every page and the timer should of course not start from the beginning even if the page is refreshed

Answer (score 0):

If you want the countdown to work across multiple browser tabs you can store the initial time in the browser's [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) which will persist between sessions. Otherwise, you will need to store the initial time in a remote system like a database.

In either case, you would want your code to first fetch the initial time then compare current time to that to determine when to `.click()` the button.

Since the `setTimeout()` and `Date.now()` methods works off milliseconds you can do basic math can tell you how to set the timeout.